# Balancing a flat rotating disk on edge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I am building a POV (persistence of vision) display, with LEDs on the edge of two different radius semicircles of a spinning disk.

[image: spinning_disk_with_support_arm]

While the structure has been designed to have its center of gravity at the center of rotation, adding the LEDs and the PCBs (which slide onto the brackets in the lower half of the structure) significantly alter the center of gravity.

I statically balanced the disk by placing the disk horizontally and adding weights to the arms until it rotated freely, although interestingly it did have a bistable tendency to be either PCBs up or PCBs down.

Now I am attempting to dynamically balance this, so I attached an accelerometer to the top axis and took measurements while it is rotating.

Here are the outputs of the accelerometer averaged over 128 rotations, with zero degrees at the point where the larger of the two semicircles passes the support arm. X acceleration is parallel to the support arm (positive values away from the support), and Y acceleration is perpendicular to the support arm.

| deg | accel_x | accel_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -8 | 10.44 |
| 10 | -6.51 | 15.27 |
| 20 | -5.04 | 13.14 |
| 30 | -2.9 | 12.62 |
| 40 | -1.98 | 8.56 |
| 50 | -0.59 | 4.62 |
| 60 | 0.78 | 2.88 |
| 70 | 5.25 | -0.38 |
| 80 | 6.81 | -3.35 |
| 90 | 7.61 | -8.79 |
| 100 | 6.18 | -11.32 |
| 110 | 3.34 | -12.81 |
| 120 | 2.13 | -12.27 |
| 130 | 1.01 | -9.73 |
| 140 | 0.14 | -4.94 |
| 150 | -1.41 | -5.11 |
| 160 | -4.13 | 3.98 |
| 170 | -6.13 | 11.68 |
| 180 | -5.22 | 16.63 |
| 190 | -4.1 | 15.43 |
| 200 | -3.52 | 11.23 |
| 210 | -1.79 | 8.34 |
| 220 | -1.29 | 2.26 |
| 230 | 0.72 | -3.81 |
| 240 | 0.26 | -7.65 |
| 250 | 4.68 | -10.98 |
| 260 | 4.64 | -10.69 |
| 270 | 7.78 | -15.54 |
| 280 | 5.41 | -17.53 |
| 290 | 1.59 | -15.45 |
| 300 | -0.44 | -8.61 |
| 310 | -2.23 | -3.13 |
| 320 | -0.76 | -0.83 |
| 330 | -3.25 | 3.66 |
| 340 | -4.69 | 7.1 |
| 350 | -6.87 | 10.12 |

Here is a graph of the data:
[image]

I am puzzled by the "double rotational frequency" component of the acceleration data, but it may be related to the bistable behavior while static balancing. I am also not sure how to approach balancing this based on the accumulated data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Reference: [[table_of_accelerations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvOzF.png)]

Comment: The 1× frequency signal comes from CG eccentricity which you took out by statically balancing it. What you have left is a principal axis of rotation which is not aligned to the rotation axis and this gives you the 2× frequency signal.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your data, there is indeed both 1× and 2× frequency components

[image: fig1]

Fitting the data into this form

$$ a = c_1 \cos(\theta) + s_1 \sin(\theta) + c_2 \cos(2 \theta) + s_2 \sin(2 \theta) $$

I get the following coefficients

| COEF | $a_x$ | $a_y$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\cos(θ)$ | $-0.87331392352282$ | $1.98854107082513$ |
| $\sin(θ)$ | $0.496753308373917$ | $2.15994995266393$ |
| $\cos(2θ)$ | $-5.75945269462699$ | $12.4496455155452$ |
| $\sin(2θ)$ | $0.126747821996927$ | $5.03747981636746$ |

The explanation for the above is that if you had a homogeneous disk spinning, but with the principal axis tilted a bit (due to geometric reasons), and because for a disk $I_{\rm axis} = 2 I_{\rm side}$ the resulting reaction torque at the supports has only a 1× component.

But for the general case, of not a homogeneous disk there are torque components proportional to the difference in MMOI when spinning form the sides $I_{\rm side1}-I_{\rm side2}$ which has a 2× frequency component.

For your data, this is the dominant mode, as the magnitude of the 2× vibrations are about 5× the magnitude of the 1× vibrations.

I noticed from the data, that there is a slight phase difference in the *x* and *y* data between the 1× and 2×. This means the body is acting not like a rigid body, but something is flexing storing elastic energy as it rotates.

In the phase-space below, you can see that not from the 45° angle of the general phase, but by the slight difference in phase between the 1× shape (overall lobes) and the 2× shape (the inner lobe).

[image: fig2]

Comment: Thank you so much for your analysis, John. That makes sense that there is both a 1x and a 2x component. Do you have any ideas on how to balance the rotating disk using the above analysis?

Comment: I am missing information to answer your question, and it is rather involved. The fact that you see accelerations (and not just reaction forces) means that you have a structural dynamic response (parts flexing) in the system making the modeling rather complex. Maybe go by trial and error, and see what happens when you add balance weights at different azimuth positions.